# What is the difference between this.function and function call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am React beginner. I've seen some code in a React project that I did not understand.

What is the difference between `this.function` and the following function call in a React event handling prop?

```
<button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button>
<button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}></button>
```

Can anyone kindly explain to me what the difference is in the example above?

Comment: None, except that the latter creates a new function each re-render. Prefer the former method. In practice though, there is no difference.

Comment: Here you can read about it in the official documentations.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: In the first also you cant pass params, the second you can

Answer (score 0):

This is **Traditional** :-

```
var obj = {
    count : 10,
    doSomethingLater : function (){
        setTimeout(function(){ // the function executes on the window scope
            this.count++;
            console.log(this.count);
        }, 300);
    }
}

obj.doSomethingLater(); // console prints "NaN", because the property "count" is not in the window scope.
```

And this is **Arrow** :-

```
var obj = {
    count : 10,
    doSomethingLater : function(){ // of course, arrow functions are not suited for methods
        setTimeout( () => { // since the arrow function was created within the "obj", it assumes the object's "this"
            this.count++;
            console.log(this.count);
        }, 300);
    }
}

obj.doSomethingLater();
```

More [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

The latter creates a useless anonymous wrapper function around this.clickHandler.

Answer (score 0):

the first one creates an anonymous function around your first function.
let's turn it into vanilla javascript (a bit modified though)

```html
<! -- equivalent to <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}></button> -->
<button id="btn-2">button 2 </button>
<script>
document.querySelector("#btn-2").addEventListener("click", function()
{
   // the above function will be created
   // executing some code
   clickHandler()
})
</script>
```

so the function nesting is just useless as you create a function whose sole purpose is to launch another function. The best way would be to do this

```html
<! -- equivalent to <button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button> -->
<button id="btn-1">button 1 </button>
<script>
// instead of an anonymous function we directly inject the function to be lauched.
document.querySelector("#btn-1").addEventListener("click", clickHandler)
</script>
```

Try to avoid function nesting as it may in some extreme case overflow your memory although it is use less. Arrow function ( => ) is a javascript `ES6` feature widely used by `React`.

Answer (score -2):

Read this:- https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.